# Running .sh file on Windows in git bash gives an error: Unable to find Digest::SHA or Digest::SHA::PurePerl

Tags: windows, git, bash, scala

Good day to all!

While trying to build a fork of scala from github on my local PC and running
**pull-binary-libs.sh** in git bash I receive such an error:

**Unable to find Digest::SHA or Digest::SHA::PurePerl**
Trouble downloading 943cd5c8802b2a3a64a010efb86ec19bac142e40/lib/ant/ant-contrib
.jar.  Please try pull-binary-libs again when your internet connection is stable

I can't figure out what's happening. I am a new bie to git, that's why maybe I am missing something. Any help will be appreceated.

P.S. I tried to install cygwin to ryn script from it, but I have problems during installation that constantly interrupt it. So I am using git bash instead.

UPDATE: I tried to install modules using СPAN. I even had successfully installed PurePerl and SH1 as CPAN messages reported. While trying to insall Digest::SHA I receive some errors connected with nmake. And while trying to run scripts again I get errors mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are missing Perl modules that Scala's build system requires.

See [How to Install CPAN Modules](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html).

Comment: I have installed PurePerl, but I continue to get this error while trying to run the script.

Comment: So... installing `Digest::SHA` failed?